# Conditioning a column that's being selected by subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have a following query

```
select distinct `orders`.`id`, `order_status`,
(SELECT `setting_id` FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`) AS `setting_id`,
from `orders` order by orders.id desc limit 100 OFFSET 0
```

which works just fine, the column "setting_id" is being fetched as it should but when I add another WHERE

```
and `setting_id` = 2
```

it cannot find it and outputs `Unknown column 'setting_id' in 'where clause'`. Why?

Comment: This is a derived column and you can't use it in the WHERE clause. Change WHERE to HAVING.

Comment: Having works, at least better than join or what i have in my question. However the performance is not great

Answer (score 2):

I would change your query to a JOIN vs selecting column.  Slower as it has to perform the column select every time.  Now, if you only want for a setting_id = 2, just add that the the JOIN portion of the condition

```
select distinct 
      o.id, 
      o.order_status,
      s.setting_id
   from 
      orders o
         join settings s
            on o.id = s.order_id
            AND s.setting_id = 2
   order by
      orders.id desc 
   limit 
      100 OFFSET 0
```

(it was also failing because you had an extra comma after your select setting column).
You could also have reversed the join by starting with your setting table so you were only concerned with those with status of 2, then finding the orders.  I would ensure that your setting table had an index on ( setting_id, order_id ) to optimize the query.

```
select distinct 
      s.order_id id, 
      o.order_status,
      s.setting_id
   from 
      settings s
         JOIN orders o
            on s.order_id = o.id
   where
      s.setting_id = 2
   order by
      s.order_id desc 
   limit 
      100 OFFSET 0
```

With proper index as suggested, the above should be lightning fast directly from the index

Another consideration for an apparent large table, is to limit the days-back you query orders to limit your 100.  Go back 1 month? 2? 15 days?  How large is your orders table to make it drag for 10 seconds.  That may be a better choice for you.

Comment: I had to change left join for subquery because of performance issues, its huge table and it was taking more than 10s

Comment: @T.Maxx, see revised answer.  With reversed query basis and proper index should be SUPER fast.